# Algorithm to allocate bonds into buckets by duration

Tags: algorithm

I tried to search for a solution, but struggled to define my problem.

**The problem:**

1. I have a list of bonds, each having a current 'market value' and a duration, e.g. 20000 and 3.25; 46000 and 1.13; etc
2. I have exactly four groups, or buckets, that I need to allocate the bonds to.
3. Three buckets have a pre-defined 'market value' and duration.  The forth bucket may have the remaining bonds not allocated to the other three, and may have any duration.
4. The goal is to allocate the bonds in such a way to fill all the buckets with bonds such that the weighted average bond duration is as close to the bucket duration as possible, and the total bond market value in that bucket is as close as possible to the bucket market value.

**The rules:**

1. All bonds have to be allocated into buckets
2. A bond may not be split, and may not be allocated to more than one bucket
3. For the first 3 buckets, the total market value of bonds in a bucket are allowed to be greater (but not smaller) than the bucket market value, but the difference should be minimised
4. The total duration of bonds in a bucket are allowed to be greater *or* smaller than the bucket duration, but the difference should be minimised.

   - To calculate total market value for bonds in a bucket: Sum (market values)
   - To calculate total duration for the bonds in a bucket: Sum (market value * duration) / Sum (Market value)

I can probably work out how to do this brute force, i.e. try *every* combination of bond in every bucket, and calculate the best combination, but I'm hoping there is a more efficient way.

I will be using excel and VBA.

Given that I am minimising two values, i.e. duration and value, I suppose I need to work out a single measure as a combination of duration and market value to minimise?

The algorithm may be an approximate one, as it will not make material difference if the solution found is not the absolute best solution possible.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Wouldnt this just be a variation of the Knapsack [problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)

Comment: After reading the wiki page, I agree, it does seem like it could be a variant of the knacksack problem. Do you perhaps know how I can apply it to my problem?

Comment: Sorry, Im not that knowledgeable when it comes to this, so any of my answers would just be a rehash of the ones given on the wiki page.